# Test lufthansa, element is not found although XPATH exists and was copied from the inspector tools by right clicking on the page and accessing HTML

Tags: user-interface, selenium-webdriver, testing, junit

I am attempting to write a Selenium script to test the Lufthansa website. I want to enter "RBA" as the origin airport and "JFK" as the destination airport. However, I am receiving the following error message despite copying the XPATH by right-clicking on the element in the inspector tools:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="dcep-af2044ca4-a2e1-47e3-934c-c8a6c9e14d0d-flm-flight-flightQuery.flightSegments[0].originCode"]"}
      (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.110)
```

This is the code I am using:

```java
package Test;
// Generated by Selenium IDE
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.After;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.not;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class AirLineTest {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private Map<String, Object> vars;
    JavascriptExecutor js;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        driver.get("https://www.lufthansa.com/ma/en/homepage");
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1552, 840));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"cm-acceptAll\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dcep-af2044ca4-a2e1-47e3-934c-c8a6c9e14d0d-flm-flight-flightQuery.flightSegments[0].originCode\"]")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dcep-af2044ca4-a2e1-47e3-934c-c8a6c9e14d0d-flm-flight-flightQuery.flightSegments[0].originCode\"]"))
              .sendKeys("RBA"); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dcep-af2044ca4-a2e1-47e3-934c-c8a6c9e14d0d-flm-flight-flightQuery.flightSegments[0].destinationCode\"]"))
              .sendKeys("JFK"); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dcep-af2044ca4-a2e1-47e3-934c-c8a6c9e14d0d-flm-flight-flightQuery.flightSegments[0].travelDatetime\"]"))
              .click();
        driver.close(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root Cause:** This XPath expression `//*[@id="dcep-af2044ca4-a2e1-47e3-934c-c8a6c9e14d0d-flm-flight-flightQuery.flightSegments[0].originCode"]` which you are using to locate the element's `ID` attribute is incorrect, because value of `ID` is dynamic. Each time the page loads the value is different. Hence change your XPath expression as shown below:

Change these lines:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dcep-af2044ca4-a2e1-47e3-934c-c8a6c9e14d0d-flm-flight-flightQuery.flightSegments[0].originCode\"]")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dcep-af2044ca4-a2e1-47e3-934c-c8a6c9e14d0d-flm-flight-flightQuery.flightSegments[0].destinationCode\"]"))
              .sendKeys("JFK");
```

To:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='From']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='To']")).sendKeys("JFK");
```

Comment: clear does not work in clearing the From field